# Normalizing Vectors to get short numbers

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, linear-programming, machine-learning, real-numbers

$\vec{A}$ is vector agent, $\vec{O}$ is vector Object, $m$ is a constant integer.

The following expression is repeated with a different O for every loop cycle:

$$\vec{A_{a}}=m\vec{A_{a-1}}+\vec{O_a}$$

The elements of $\vec{A}$ and $\vec{O}$ are real numbers and after $a$ loop cycles the numbers become very big in terms of magnitude and significant figures. This means i must normalize the result on each loop cycle. When using $$\vec{A_{a}}=\frac{m\vec{A_{a-1}}+\vec{O_a}}{|m\vec{A_{a-1}}+\vec{O_a}|}$$ to normalize the result, the numbers are still long.

The problem boils down to finding a number, that when it divides all elements of A yields the shortest/nicest numbers. Is there such thing? If not, what would be the best way to simplify this vector? I am not concerned with the vector's magnitude- only its direction, while maintaining computability of the numbers.

Comment: What do you mean that when you normalize the result "the numbers are still long"? The components will all be bounded between $-1$ and $1$.

Comment: long as in there are a lot of digits. yes they are between -1 and 1, but they are long decimals.